# Fire second httpRequest after parsing data from first request

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I currently have a function which makes a `httpRequest` and parses the `json` received into an `array` of urls. I want to fire a second `httpRequest` after the first request is complete and data is parse, below both solutions I've tried return null.

**Solution1**

```
var promises1 = [];
Parse.Cloud.define("FetchData", function(request, response) {
    var promises = _.map(urls, function(url) {
        return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({ url:url });
        });
    Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function() {
        createSearchUrls(arguments)
        //Creates an array of urls from request data to be used in second http request
         });       
    //Fire second HTTP request here after urls have been created from first request data
    var promises1 = _.map(appTitles, function(appTitles) {
        return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({ url: appTitles});
        });
    Parse.Promise.when(promises1).then(function() {
        //nothing returned
        response.success(_.toArray(arguments));
        }, function (error) {
            response.error("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        });
    });
```

**Solution 2 (Using `then` after `createSearchUrl()` function**

```
    Parse.Cloud.define("FetchData1", function(request, response) {
        var promises = _.map(urls, function(url) {
            return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({ url:url });
            });
        Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function() {
  //Creates an array of urls from request data to be used in second http request
            createSearchUrls(arguments).then( function() {
                //Fire second HTTP request here after urls have been created from first request data
                promises_1 = _.map(appTitles, function(appTitles) {
                    return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({ url: appTitles});
                    });
                })
            });
       Parse.Promise.when(promises_1).then(function() {
            //nothing returned
            response.success(_.toArray(arguments));
            }, function (error) {
                response.error("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            });
        });
```

**createSearchUrls()**

```
function createSearchUrls(arguments){
    for (a = 0; a < arguments.length; a++){
        var json = JSON.parse(arguments[a].text);
        for (i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++) {
            var urlEncoded = encodeURI(ENCODE JSON DATA);
            var finalUrl = 'URL HERE';

            appTitles.push(finalUrl);
        }
    }
    return appTitles;
}
```

Comment: The second block of code is closer to correct, but needs some fixing, too.  Can you post the full source?  (Though, its totally appreciated when the OP tries to simplify to a minimal case, you might have snipped out too much).

Comment: @danh only thing missing was the `createSearchUrls` function and a variable declaration. Question has been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the idea of making a series of httpRequests and collecting the results is something that can and should be factored out....

```
function manyRequests(urls) {
    var promises = _.map(urls, function(url) {
        return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({ url:url });
    });
    return Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function() {
        return _.toArray(arguments);
    });
}
```

Now its just a matter of calling that twice....

```
Parse.Cloud.define("FetchData1", function(request, response) {
    manyRequests(urls).then(function(results) {
        createSearchUrls(results);  // assigns to the gobal "appTitles"
        return manyRequests(appTitles);
    }).then(function(result) {
        response.success(result);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

What that says is, call (a globally defined, presumably) list of urls and collect the results.  From those results, run a local function to generate another list of urls (assigning those to a global, presumably), call those and return the result to the client.

Comment: For some strange reason `manyRequest` returns only the header of the response second time its called. (Thought there was a mistake in my urls but I've tested with an array of different urls, i still receive the same result)

Comment: Can you post the log of the urls and results of the second call?

Comment: Sorry @danh you can disregard that last comment. It works with a static array of urls but not with `appTitles`. (I'm guessing `createSearchUrls` is not  completed before `manyRequest` is executed again.) Here's a screenshot of the [results](http://i.imgur.com/ASfas6u.png)

Comment: `createSearchUrls` runs synchronously.  so it definitely finishes before the second call to many requests.  Maybe try logging appTitles and try running them with CURL